# Datagrip EXPLAIN ANALYZE Gui?

Tags: datagrip

In Datagrip (using 2018.2.4), you can right-click on a query and choose 'Explain' which gives nicely formatted output. Is there anyway to get this nicely formatted output using instead 'Explain Analyze'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE FROM 2022:**
The feature is available:
[image]

---

Unfortunately, not yet, Bob =( https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-5373

Comment: Thanks - I upvoted the issue on you track.